# Input File async in ASP UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asynchronous, input

I'm trying to pass the contents of an input file asynchronously. The input control is located within an UpdatePanel control. I can only use the HTML input file control and I do not want to generate the postback. Ok. Is there a way, even using JavaScript? To understand better: in my project I must be able to publish posts (like facebook) that have an image besides the text. Therefore it must take place asynchronously. When the user loads the image, the preview is generated by saving the cached data.

```
<img id="imgoutput"/>
<input id="upload1" type="file" name="upload1" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)" />

var loadFile = function (event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('imgoutput');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

Is there a way to somehow manage to recover the file by acting on the cache when I try to publish the post?

Thank you

Comment: The ajaxtoolkit `AsyncFileUpload` control might be useful to you http://www.ajaxtoolkit.net/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx

Comment: Hello. I wrote that I can only use HTML input file control for graphic reasons